# Why am I not able to pass two status Ids in my GET method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-restful, pypika

I have a scenario where in I need to compare two simulation coming from same table, i.e say simulation_1 and simulation_2. For all completed simulation theer would be a unique id generated "sim_sttus_id" in the "__TABLE1" as shown in the code snippet. Below are the code snippet for reference.

```
class SimRes:
    __TABLE1 = 'SIM_STTUS'
    __TABLE2 = 'COMP_SIM_CONF'
    __TABLE3 = 'COMP'

    def __init__(self, prog: str, plan: int, versn: float, sim_sttus: int, tab_name: str = None, comp_id: int = None):
        super().__init__(prog)
        self.__prog = prog
        self.__plan = plan
        self.__versn = versn
        self.__sim_sttus = sim_sttus
        self.__tab_name = tab_name
        self.__comp_id = comp_id
        self.__sim_sttus_tbl = Table(f'{self.schema_name}.{self.__TABLE1}')
        self.__comp_sim_conf_tbl = Table(f'{self.schema_name}.{self.__TABLE2}')
        self.__comp_tbl = Table(f'{self.schema_name}.{self.__TABLE3}')
        


def get_select_comp(self):
        try:
            SSD = self.__sim_sttus_tbl
            CSCD = self.__comp_sim_conf_tbl
            ICD = self.__comp_tbl

            query = SnowflakeQuery.from_(CSCD) \
                .join(SSD).on_field('PLAN_SIM_CONF_ID') \
                .join(ICD).on_field('COMP_ID') \
                .select(CSCD.COMP_SIM_CONF_ID, SSD.sim_sttus_id, CSCD.PLAN_SIM_CONF_ID, \
                        CSCD.COMP_ID, ICD.COMP_NAME) \
                .where(Criterion.all([SSD.sim_sttus_id == self.sim_sttus_id])) \
                .get_sql()

            comp_lst = self.execute_query(query)
            if isinstance(component_lists['result'], str):
                raise QueryException(component_lists)
            return comp_lst["result"]
        except Exception as e:
            raise
```

My challenge lies in the below function where I need to compare

```
   def compare_sim_sttus(self, sttus_id1, sttus_id2):
        try:
            selected_comp = self.get_select_comp()

            matching_comp = []
            for component in selected_components:
                if component['sim_sttus_id'] == sttus_id1:
                    comp_id = component['comp_id']
                    comp_name = component['comp_name']

                    if self.__check_component_status(comp_id, sttus_id2):
                        matching_comp.append((comp_id, comp_name))

            return matching_comp
        except Exception as e:
            raise


    def __check_comp_sttus(self, comp_id, sttus_id):
        try:
            query = SnowflakeQuery \
                .from_(self.__sim_sttus_tbl) \
                .where(self.__sim_sttus_tbl.sim_sttus_id == sttus_id) \
                .where(self.__comp_tbl.COMP_ID == comp_id) \
                .get_sql()

            comp_sttus = self.execute_query(query)
            return len(comp_sttus['result']) > 0
        except Exception as e:
            raise
```

- "`get_select_comp`" method is using PyPika query to get list of `comp_name` and `comp_id` based on `sim_sttus_id`. Its working as per the method requirement.
- `compare_sim_sttus` which internally calls the existing "get_select_comp" method to retrieve the list of selected components. Then, we iterate over each component and check if its sim_sttus_id matches sttus_id1. If it does, we retrieve the comp_id and comp_name and call the "check_comp_sttus" method to verify if the same comp_id exists for sttus_id2. If it does, we add the component to the matching_components list.

Below is the below endpoint code.

```
import traceback
from flasgger import swag_from
from flask_restful import Resource
from pathlib import Path
from <path_to_module import SimRes

__all__ = ['SimRes']

class SimResResource(Resource):

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, prog: str, plan: int, versn: float, sim_sttus_id: int):
        try:
            sttus_id1 = 1  # Set the first sim_sttus_id
            sttus_id2 = 2  # Set the second sim_sttus_id

            components_compare = SimRes(prog=prog, plan=plan, versn=versn, sim_sttus_id=sim_sttus_id)
            response = components_compare.compare_sim_sttus(sttus_id1, sttus_id2)
            return success_response(response)
        except Exception as e:
            app.logger.error(f'{str(e)}: {traceback.format_exc()}')
            return error_response(e)
```

As you can see that in the above GET method I have passed the values for `sttus_id1` and `status_id2` which is hard coded. But I need to execute the API in POSTMAN, and I wanted to pass the sttus_id1 and sttus_id2 in the POSTMAN API and get the response.

below would be the endpoint route

```
/programs/<prog>/plans/<plan>/<versn>/sim_compare.
```

I am not able to figure out how to do that in my endpoint. I couldn't pass `"sim_sttus_id"` twice in my endpoint path, as it is giving me error saying `"identical col name"` and when I am passing `<sttus_id1>/<sttus_id2>` in the endpoint path, I am getting below error.

```
{
    "error": "__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sttus_id1'",
    "success": false
}
```

So, I tried adding those two variables sttus_id1, and sttus_id2 in the class constructor, and removed them as a parameters from the `compare_sim_sttus` method and call them with "self" at the required positions. In the endpoint class I added them as parameters in the GET method, but no help. As, when I did, I am getting below error

```
    "error": "__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sim_sttus_id'",
    "success": false
}
```

modified endpoint path `/programs/<prog_id>/plans/<plan>/<versn>/<sttus_id1>/<sttus_id2>/sim_compare`
I cannot pass sim_sttus_id in the endpoint as said earlier. Kindly suggest

Comment: How about passing the ids as a list via a query string rather than as part of the route path

Comment: plz give an example. so that I can follow it. Thank you